# How can I accept JSON as string in Jersey

Tags: java, javascript, json, jersey

I am trying to maintain some logs of a couple of Javascript objects in my webapp. The easiest way to log them would be to stringify them and put them on a jersey path as a string.

My logger works fine with regular strings but gives ***Error 400: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect*** when I pass a JSON stringified object. There are two things that I can't explain and are going wrong with my code:

1. Everything seems to be working fine on my development server but not on the server where I am deploying it. I develop on a Mac / Homebrew / Tomcat enviroment and deploy on a CentOS server.
2. Even on the CentOS server, logging works fine when I pass a simple one word strings as message but passing a JSON string throws up the error.

My Logger code looks like this:

```
@PUT
@Path("logEvent/{fn_event}/{fn_message}")
public void logEvent(@PathParam("fn_event") String event,
        @PathParam("fn_message") String message)
        throws Exception {

        :
        :
        :

}
```

I have tried investigating catalina logs but it doesn't tell anything. Access logs give no more information than specifying "Error 400".

Comment: Please include what went wrong in the description of the question. Often, the specific error message will give a good clue for what is needed to solve the issue.

Comment: Don't use json as path segments. Especially since you're using a put request. Send it in the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json String may be having "Spaces" etc etc.

So when you call http://yourserver/logEvent/oneword/onewordMessage it may work fine but when you call http://yourserver/logEvent/oneword with space and with & and so many things/or one message with " and not " etc

Then in second case, your path may be incorrectly encoded. Form Encode your json stream, and then pass it as path.

Better move to Post, and pass the stream as Body of Request. Not sure why you will prefer using "entire" json file as path of your service

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if you don't escape quotes in your JSON string. Try to escape it with \"